# How do I document cash capital contribution and digital assets assignment for single member LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, start-up

I have a single member LLC, which is currently a disregarded entity status (will be upgraded to S-Corp within a month or two).

I'm making an initial capital contribution via cash deposit while opening a new business bank account.

I will also be transferring the following technological assets/IP:

1. Proprietary Software & Server Configuration
2. Domain name
3. PayPal Account
4. Online Marketplace Account

What is the best way to document the cash contribution?

Also, what is the appropriate legal documentation for assigning the above assets?

The marketplace account and associated paypal account will be assumed by the business. I'd like to ensure that the documentation clearly demonstrates that from that point in time forward, all transactions will belong to the business, while *anything prior does not*.

What is the proper way to document that?